# <ul> elements not vertically aligning with DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a header for a webpage, and I would like the title of the webpage (far left of the screen) to be centered vertically with the elements on the far right of the screen. I thought having `float: left;` applied to the "title" div would resolve this issue, but it doesn't.

I've included the code & snippet to show you what I mean. I've also included a box-shadow for each element so you can visualize them better.

```css
* {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav>ul>li:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.nav>ul {
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.nav>.title>p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab|Roboto+Slab:bold,italic,underline">

<div class="nav">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Forums</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height css property to set the amount of space used for lines.

```
.nav > .title > p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:2.5;      // add this line 
}
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3)}
* {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Roboto Slab;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.nav > ul > li:hover {
 color: #cccccc;
}
.nav > ul {
 text-align: right;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.nav {
 background-color: #111111;
}
.nav > .title > p {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: Roboto Slab;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left;
    padding: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<script rel="javascript" src="Website.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Website.css"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab|Roboto+Slab:bold,italic,underline">
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<div class="title">
<p>Title</p>
</div>
 <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Forums</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `p element of title class a margin of 15px on top`.

Hope this updated code will work for you.

```css
* {box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3)}
* {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Roboto Slab;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.nav > ul > li:hover {
 color: #cccccc;
}
.nav > ul {
 text-align: right;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.nav {
 background-color: #111111;
}
.nav > .title > p {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: Roboto Slab;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 25px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<script rel="javascript" src="Website.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Website.css"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab|Roboto+Slab:bold,italic,underline">
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<div class="title">
<p>Title</p>
</div>
 <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Forums</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to only give `.nav`  below style. Please make sure you also user prefix of flex;
you can also make vertical align center by giving `.title` and `ul` `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`

```
.nav {
  background-color: #111111;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav>ul>li:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.nav>ul {
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #111111;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav>.title>p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab|Roboto+Slab:bold,italic,underline">

<div class="nav">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Forums</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```